# PostgreSQL UPDATE ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, subquery

```
UPDATE t1 SET cat_id = (SELECT t2.id FROM t3 JOIN t1 ON t2.name=t3.cat);
```

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: As the error says your subquery returns multiple values. A column can only have a single value. You didn’t explain what you’re trying to achieve so cannot answer. Please edit the question and explain the problem

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.  A non-working query is not particularly helpful, especially when the error is based on your *data* and not on the *syntax*.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

In this situation either use IN clause OR make sur that your select statement should always return single row.

Answer (score 0):

First, `t2` is not defined in your expression.  So the error should really be that is undefined.

Second, you seem to want a correlated subquery.  If so, you don't `join` in the subquery:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET cat_id = (SELECT t3.id FROM t3 WHERE t1.name = t3.cat)
```